# How to write unit test case for edit functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, edit

I have to test edit functionality.I have tested add functionality by creating new object and passed it to add method .But how to pass those added value to  test edit functionality by editing them  using Id.I used mocking concept to test add functionality.I need to pass already added value to edit method for testing it by editing.

Test case for Add functionality:

public void AddTote()
        {

```
        var toteRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Tote>>();

        var partToteRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<PartTote>>();

        var partRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Part>>();

        var auditRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Audit>>();

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Commit());
        var tote = new ToteDL(toteRep.Object, partToteRep.Object, partRep.Object, mockUnitOfWork.Object, auditRep.Object);
        ToteDTO toteDto = new ToteDTO();
        toteDto.Id = 1;
        toteDto.Name = "adds";
        toteDto.Description = "testing";
        Assert.AreEqual(true, tote.AddTote(toteDto).IsSuccess);

    }
```

Test case for Edit functionality:

public void EditTote()
        {

```
        var toteRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Tote>>();

        var partToteRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<PartTote>>();

        var partRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Part>>();

        var auditRep = new Mock<IEntityBaseRepository<Audit>>();

        var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        mockUnitOfWork.Setup(uow => uow.Commit());
        var tote = new ToteDL(toteRep.Object, partToteRep.Object, partRep.Object, mockUnitOfWork.Object, auditRep.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, tote.EditTote(toteRep.Object).IsSuccess);

}
```

Edit Method which need to be tested:

```
  public ResponseDTO EditTote(ToteDTO toteData)
    {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();
        try
        {
            var tote = this._toteRepository.GetSingle(toteData.Id);
            tote.Name = toteData.Name;
            tote.Description = toteData.Description;
            this._toteRepository.Edit(tote);
            audit = AuditMessage.GetAuditForFile(toteData.Name + " tote has been updated successfully.", (int)Enumerations.ModuleType.Tote, (int)Enumerations.OperationType.EditTote, 1);
            _auditRepository.Add(audit);
            this._unitOfWork.Commit();
            responseDTO.ResponseObject = tote;
            responseDTO.IsSuccess = true;
            responseDTO.UserMessage = tote.Name + " has been updated.";
        }
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the relevant mocking framework. Is it Moq? If so the call to Setup in AddTote is redundant. Also note that the AddTote test seems weak to me: if I edited ToteDL's AddTote method to do nothing other than return the object with IsSuccess set to true, the test would pass but the code probably doesn't do what you want. So the test isn't adding much value. You could at least `Verify` that your repository was called with the right object.

Comment: yes,I am using moq framework,Thanks for your feedback .can you suggest me how to pass added data values to edit method while testing to test edit functionality without creating new object.  
            Assert.AreEqual(true, tote.EditTote(how to pass data in this parameter).IsSuccess);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but when testing edit: use your mock toteRepository call `Verify(It.Is<Tote>(x=>x.Name == *value that you wanted* && *similar for description*)`. By the way `tote.EditTote(toteRep.Object)` is clearly wrong as you need to give it a dto whose Id corresponds with a setup of GetSingle on your mock repository. May I suggest you read the [Moq quickstart guide](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link.I had problem in passing data values to edit method,where name=adds ,description=testing which added while testing add functionality   .how to pass this value and write test case to  test editing functionality.I mean to edit testing as test.I did verify like you mentioned above        toteRep.Verify(a=>a.Add( It.Is<Tote>(x => x.Name == "adds" )));